# Webapp2 Redirect Method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am trying to redirect a POST request from an Google App Engine Python Handler to another URL. The Problem is that it seems the method is changed to GET. Is there any way to set the POST method when redirecting?

Comment: try using 307, which should not change the request method

Comment: what is 307 ?? what do you mean?

Comment: The redirect code. Docs : https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html?highlight=redirect#webapp2.redirect

Comment: ok it worked, post the answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 307 redirect. A 307 will not change the method of the redirect.

Wikipedia: 307 temporary redirect (provides a new URL for the browser to resubmit a GET or POST request)